# Finding cause for ASP Error

Tags: iis, asp-classic

I have a simple bit of code on my classic ASP website to send me an email when a page errors, as I have this set up in my web.config to point at a page to handle errors:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL">
    <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="100" />
    <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
    <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
    <error statusCode="404" path="/error_404.asp" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    <error statusCode="500" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/error_500.asp" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    <error statusCode="500" subStatusCode="100" path="/error_500.asp" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

This is my simple bit of code:

```
...
set objError =          Server.getLastError()
strNumber =             objError.AspCode
strSource =             objError.Category
strDesc =               newstr(objError.Description)
strCode =               newstr(objError.Source)
strLine =               ObjError.Line
strASPDesc =            ObjError.ASPDescription
strRemoteAddr =         Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")
ref =                   request.servervariables("HTTP_REFERER")
str =                   request.servervariables("QUERY_STRING")
cookies =               request.servervariables("HTTP_COOKIE")
ip_url =                strRemoteAddr
ua =                    newstr(request.servervariables("HTTP_USER_AGENT"))
totalstring =           objError.File & "?" & str
```

I then concatenate those values together and email the details to myself.

For an error, I'd get something like this:

```
strNumber: ASP 0126
strSource: Active Server Pages
strDesc: Include file not found
strCode:
strLine: 14
strASPDesc: The include file '/news/aw.asp' was not found.
strRemoteAddr: 2.101.166.175
ref: http://example.com/sites/support/
str: page=cd
cookies: usr1=62105233D8E2A062A55; fantastic%5Fcheese=1; _ga=GA1.3.1357551757.1476543431; __atuvc=2%7C41%2C1%7C42%2C0%7C43%2C0%7C44%2C9%7C45; __utma=154830755.1357551757.1476543431.1476822981.1479368067.3; __utmz=154830755.1476818175.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); ASPSESSIONIDQCBABQAR=KHGBAMBCCCENHCIPPCOFBJOO; __utmb=154830755.1.10.1479368067; __utmc=154830755; __utmt=1
ip_url: 84.92.46.118
ua: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0
totalstring: /sites/support/page.asp?landscape=cd
```

However, I often only see this error:

```
strNumber:
strSource:
strDesc:
strCode:
strLine: 0
strASPDesc:
strRemoteAddr: 43.247.156.6
ref: http:/example.com/content/this.asp
str: 500;http://jimpix.co.uk:80/words/check-username.asp
cookies: ASPSESSIONIDSAABARBQ=ACDDOHOCEKIEFOCKFBFIHJBC; _gat=1; __atuvc=129%7C46; __atuvs=582e898682f62926059; _ga=GA1.3.491207786.1479439414
ip_url: 43.247.156.6
ua: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36
totalstring: ?500;http:/example.com:80/content/this.asp
```

There are no error details as such, but it's always on the same page. I can't work out what's causing it.

Is there any more detailed error logging I can do to find out more?

Answer (score 0):

`Server.getLastError()` only remains populated until the response buffer has started to flush content to the client, reasons for this could be:

1. `response.buffer` is set to false
2. `response.flush` has been called
3. `response.end` has been called

There is a reference to this in the documentation:

> [This method is available only before the .asp file has sent any
>   content to the client.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524846(v=vs.90).aspx)

This is the only thing i can think of that would explain why your `Server.getLastError()` seems to be blank.